# 'import module' vs. 'from module import function'

Tags: python

I have always been using this method:

```
from sys import argv
```

and use `argv` with just **argv**. But there is a convention of using this:

```
import sys
```

and using the argv by `sys.argv`

The second method makes the code self documented and I *(really)* adhere to it. But the reason I prefer first method is it is fast because we are importing only the function that is needed rather than import the whole module (which contains more useless functions which python will waste time importing them). Note that I need just argv and all other functions from sys are useless to me.

So my questions are. Does the first method really makes the script fast? Which method is preferred most? Why?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/710551/321973

Comment: Related post - [Reasoning behind `from … import …` syntax in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3600352/465053)

Answer (score 262, accepted):

Importing the module doesn't waste *anything*; the module is always *fully* imported (into the `sys.modules` mapping), so whether you use `import sys` or `from sys import argv` makes no odds.

The only difference between the two statements is what name is bound; `import sys` binds the name `sys` to the module (so `sys` -> `sys.modules['sys']`), while `from sys import argv` binds a different name, `argv`, pointing straight at the attribute contained inside of the module (so `argv` -> `sys.modules['sys'].argv`). The rest of the `sys` module is still there, whether you use anything else from the module or not.

There is also no performance difference between the two approaches. Yes, `sys.argv` has to look up two things; it has to look up `sys` in your global namespace (finds the module), then look up the attribute `argv`. And yes, by using `from sys import argv` you can skip the attribute lookup, since you already have a direct reference to the attribute. But the `import` statement still has to do that work, it looks up the same attribute when importing, and you'll only ever need to use `argv` *once*. If you had to use `argv` thousands of times in a loop, it could perhaps make a difference, but in this specific case it really does not.

Hence, the choice between one or the other should be based solely on *coding style*.

In a *large* module, I'd certainly use `import sys`; code documentation matters, and using `sys.argv` somewhere in a large module makes it much clearer what you are referring to than just `argv` ever would.

If the only place you use `argv` is in a `'__main__'` block to call a `main()` function, by all means use `from sys import argv` if you feel happier about that:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from sys import argv
    main(argv)
```

I'd still use `import sys` there myself. All things being equal (and they are, exactly, in terms of performance *and* number of characters used to write it), that is just easier on the eye for me.

If you are importing something *else* altogether, then perhaps performance comes into play. But only if you use a specific name in a module *many times over*, in a critical loop for example. But then creating a local name (within a function) is going to be faster still:

```
 import somemodule

 def somefunction():
      localname = somemodule.somefunctionorother
      while test:
          # huge, critical loop
          foo = localname(bar)
```

Comment: There is also the situation where you have a package with subpackages or modules that exposes an attribute of one of those subpackages/modules in the top level package. Using `from...import` allows you to do `package.attribute` rather than `package.subpackage_or_module.attribute`, which can be useful if you have logical or conceptual groupings within the package but want to make things a bit more convenient for users of your package. (`numpy` does something like this, I believe.)

Comment: In django you have tons of spots where things like `from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand` are better,and anything else (especially `import django`) would lead to unreadable code. So while I like this answer, I think there are some libraries (and especially some frameworks) in which the convention is to violate the bare import. As always, use your judgment about what is best in a given situation. But err on the side of explicit (in other words I agree for the most part).

Comment: @JAB: you can still use `import ... as` to find the package to a different name: `import package.subpackage_or_module as shortname`. `from parent import sub` does, essentially, the same thing.

Comment: `so wether you use import sys or from sys import argv makes no odds` this seems to be not the case with IDLE. just importing the module does not import its functions and I can call it in IDLE shell only by <module>.<function> name

Comment: @Suncatcher: do read my answer in full. The sentence you quote talks about how much is being imported, not what name is bound. That's covered elsewhere in the answer.

Comment: You make it sound as if `from sys import argv` makes available not only `argv`, but also anything else from `sys` and that it can be accessed in `sys.modules`. This doesn't seem to be true: accessing anything from `sys` *(including a `sys.modules['sys']`)* says `name 'sys' is not defined`.

Comment: @Hi-Angel `sys` is clearly special; `sys.modules['sys']` would be a circular reference, for example. But for **any other module** what I wrote holds; `sys` just happens to always exist and is a already “imported”.

Comment: Alright, so, after doing more experiments, I seem to got this working. Though it is important to note that accessing `sys.modules` requires `sys` to be imported; it doesn't just magically appears in the visibility scope *(which is the feeling I get from reading the first 2 paragraphs of your answer)*.

Comment: There is a good discussion of different styles of `import` at https://stackoverflow.com/q/9916878

Answer (score 59):

There are two reasons in favor of using `import module` rather than `from module import function`.

First is the namespace. Importing a function into the global namespace risks name collisions.

Second isn't that relevant to standard modules, but significant for you own modules,  especially during development. It's the option to `reload()` a module. Consider this:

```
from module import func
...
reload(module)
# func still points to the old code
```

On the other hand

```
import module
...
reload(module)
# module.func points to the new code
```

As for speed...

> we are importing only the function that is needed rather than import
>   the whole module (which contains more useless functions which python
>   will waste time importing them)

Whether you import a module or import a function from a module, Python will parse the whole module. Either way the module is imported. "Importing a function" is nothing more than binding the function to a name. In fact `import module` is less work for interpreter than `from module import func`.

Comment: reload() was a builtin in Python 2; that is no longer the case for Python 3.

Comment: I thought there were also implications to do with circular import dependencies?

Comment: @André `importlib.reload` is the Python3 way of doing it now: https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload

Comment: @vartec, I was linked to this question because I am doing some programs where specific numpy functions may be used trillions of times, taking days to complete even simple physical simulations. Minimizing the number of calls is not possible without rewriting the entire application in C to begin with. As such minimizing the number of times python has to search the local namespace _and_ the numpy namespace is of top priority.

Answer (score 35):

I use `from import`s whenever it improves readability. For example, I prefer (semicolons are only to save space here):

```
from collections import defaultdict
from foomodule import FooBar, FooBaz
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory
defaultdict(); FooBar(); FooBaz(); Factory()
```

instead of:

```
import collections
import foomodule
import twisted.internet.protocol
collections.defaultdict(); foomodule.FooBar(); foomodule.FooBaz()
twisted.internet.protocol.Factory()
```

The latter is harder to read (and write) for me because it contains so much redundant information. Also, it's useful to know ahead of time what parts of a module I'm using.

I prefer regular `import`s if I'm using lots of short names from a module:

```
import sys
sys.argv; sys.stderr; sys.exit()
```

Or if a name is so generic that it doesn't make sense outside of its namespace:

```
import json
json.loads(foo)

from json import loads
loads(foo)  # potentially confusing
```

Comment: This is my favorite answer. 'Explicit is better than implicit' sometimes conflicts with readability, simplicity, and DRY. Especially when  using a framework like Django.

Answer (score 22):

In my opinion using regular `import` improves readability. When reviewing Python code I like seeing where the given function or class comes from right where it is used. It saves me from scrolling to the top of the module to get that info.

As for the long module names I just use the `as` keyword and give them short aliases:

```
import collections as col
import foomodule as foo
import twisted.internet.protocol as twip

my_dict = col.defaultdict()
foo.FooBar()
twip_fac = twip.Factory()
```

As an exception I always use the `from module import something` notation when I deal with the `__future__` module. You just can't do it another way when you want all strings to be unicode by default in Python 2, e.g.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from __future__ import print_function
```

Comment: Amen! "import as" is a winning combination :-)

Answer (score 4):

Although `import sys` and `from sys import agrv` both import the entire `sys` module, the latter uses name binding so only the `argv` module is accessible to rest of the code.

For some people this would be the preferred style since it only makes accessible the function you explicitly stated.

It does however introduce potential name conflicts. What if you had another module named `argv`? Note you can also explicitly import the function and rename with `from sys import argv as sys_argv`, a convention that meets the explicit import and is less likely to gave name space collisions.

Comment: So how is `if sys_argv:` any better than `if sys.argv:`? I know what the second statement means, I have no idea what the first form means without backtracking to the bizarre import.

Answer (score 1):

I recently asked this question to myself. I timed the different methods.

requests library

```
def r():
    import requests
    return 'hello'
timeit r() # output: 1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.55 µs per loop

def rg():
    from requests import get
    return 'hello'
timeit rg() # output: 100000 loops, best of 3: 2.53 µs per loop
```

beautifulsoup library

```
def bs():
    import bs4
    return 'hello' 
timeit bs() # output: 1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.53 µs per loop

def be():
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    return 'hello'
timeit be() # output: 100000 loops, best of 3: 2.59 µs per loop
```

json library

```
def js():
    import json
    return 'hello'
timeit js() # output: 1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.53 µs per loop

def jl():
    from json import loads
    return 'hello'
timeit jl() # output: 100000 loops, best of 3: 2.56 µs per loop
```

sys library

```
def s():
    import sys
    return 'hello'
timeit s() # output: 1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.55 µs per loop

def ar():
    from sys import argv
    return 'hello'
timeit ar() # output: 100000 loops, best of 3: 2.87 µs per loop
```

It seems to me that *there is* a slight difference in performance.

Comment: You are adding in an attribute lookup. To compare `import module` with `from module import name` correctly, *add* that name lookup to the `import module` case. E.g. add the line `sys.argv` to the `ar` test, etc. There will still be a difference, because the work done is *slightly* different, as different bytecode is generated and different codepaths are executed.

Comment: Note that I directly address that difference in my answer; there will be a difference between using `import sys` then using `sys.argv` thousands of time in a loop vs. `from sys import argv` then using just `argv`. But you don't. For things you do just *once* at the global level of your module, you really should optimise for readability, not microscopic differences in timings.

Comment: Ahhhh! And I thought I was on to something! :) I only skimmed your answer. Looks like I jumped the gun on that one. Feels good to be humbled.

Comment: Information is misleading as it lacks the lookup to the module to render usefull results.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at published code fragments, importing entire modules and referring to `module.function` is pretty much the standard, at least for standard modules. The one exception seems to be `datetime`

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
```

so you can say `datetime.now()` rather than `datetime.datetime.now()`.

If you are concerned about performance, you can always say (for example)

```
argv = sys.argv
```

and then do your performance critical code since the module lookup is already done.  However although this will work with functions/methods, most IDE's will get confused and won't (for example) display a source link/signature for the function when it's assigned to a variable.

Answer (score -2):

I just want to add that if you do something like

```
from math import sin
```

(or any other built-in library like `sys` or `posix`), then `sin` will be included in the documentation for your module (ie when you do `>>> help(mymodule)` or `$ pydoc3 mymodule`. To avoid this, import using:

```
import math
from math import sin as _sin
```

PS: a built-in library is one that is compiled from C code and included with Python. `argparse`, `os` and `io` are not built-in packages